# Yii2: Conditional validation doesn't work on resubmit

Tags: validation, yii2

I have a conditional field client side validation enabled - basically containerPrice is required if the value of radio button isContainerInlcluded equals to 1.

**Validation rules**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
            [['monthlyTakeawayOrders', 'isContainerIncluded'], 'required'],
            ['containerPrice', 'required', 'when' => function($model){
                return $model->isContainerIncluded;
                }, 'whenClient' => "function(attribute, value) {
                    return $('#pricingform-iscontainerincluded input:checked').val() == 1;
                }"
            ],
            [['monthlyTakeawayOrders', 'containerPrice'],'integer']

    ];
}
```

**The form**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'pricing-form']); ?>

                <?= $form->field($pricingForm, 'monthlyTakeawayOrders') ?>

                <?= $form->field($pricingForm, 'isContainerIncluded')->radioList([
                        0 => 'Option 0',
                        1 => 'Option 1'
                ]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($pricingForm, 'containerPrice') ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Calculate', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'pricing-button']) ?>
                </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**Processing action**

```
public function actionPartners()
{

    $pricingForm = new PricingForm();

    // pricing calculation processing
    if ($pricingForm->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $rates = $pricingForm->calculatePrice();
        $shipping = $pricingForm->calculateShipping($rates['reducedRate']);
        $table = $pricingForm->buildTable($rates['reducedRate']);

        return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
                'rates' => $rates,
                'shipping' => $shipping,
                'deposit' => PricingForm::REBOX_DEPOSIT,
                'table' => $table,
                'isContainerIncluded' => $pricingForm->isContainerIncluded
        ]);
    }

    // get content
    $products = ProductHelper::getProducts()->results;
    $cmsApi = PrismicHelper::initiate();
    $partnersHomepage = $cmsApi->getSingle('partners_homepage');

    return $this->render('partners', [
            'pricingForm' => $pricingForm,
            'partnersHomepage' => $partnersHomepage,
            'products' => $products,
    ]);
}
```

In most cases, it works just fine but when I submit the form with isContainerInlcluded on 0, then switch it to 1 and submit again (without filling containerPrice), the validation is not triggered and form is submitted, eventhough containerPrice should be required.

In addition, after performing the steps above, if I focus on the containerPrice field and then submit, error message is displayed but the form is submitted anyway.

The form is sort of a price calculator and I submit it through ajax, so there is no page refresh performed after submit as it is required that user can change their input and resubmit the form again to see instant results.

I don't know why this is happening, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to rebuild this, but could not reproduce your problem - could you also provide the action that recieves the form?

Comment: can you confirm when you toggle there isnt any other scripts bind to the button on that page, or do you get nay javascript errors in the console. and when you say form is submitted do you mean the server side validation is also not called and the record is saved ?

Comment: I've added the action to the question.

Comment: When I toggle, there are no errors in console and there is no js binded to the action yet. 

We don't have serverside validation for this form as it's not critical.

I was playing around a bit more and it seems, that in the scenarios I mentioned, validation is not performed as event beforeValidate is not called at all. On the other hand, afterValidate is being triggered many times in some kind of a weird loop. Event beforeSubmit is triggered correctly.

We use this to handle ajax submision: https://github.com/ronysilvati/yii2-ajax-request/blob/master/yii2AjaxRequest.js